# Receive data from other apps with a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mime

I am building a chat app where I already finished the chatting feature so now I want to add a sharing feature. Something like if you go to a video on youtube app and click share, a dialog appears listing the apps that you can share the video with. I have a fragment where all the chats appear, now I need to achieve the following things:

1. When the user clicks the app in share via dialog the fragment containing the chats should pop up.
2. After the above step is done the user should be able to click on desired chat to share the desired data like in whatsapp.

What I noticed is  we can't pop up a fragment because we can't specify the MIME types or actions to a fragment in a manifest file.

Edit 1 : As per Lalit's advice i solved and achieved my first step.Now i need an approach to the second step.

Even a little approach is appreciated Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't give an intent filter to a `Fragment`, but you can certainly give it to the "`Activity` that contains the `Fragment`" in the AndroidManifest.

After the `Activity` opens, you may switch to that `Fragment`.

Comment: Yes Lalit i solved my first problem as mentioned in my question thanks so do you know how to take an approach to the second one that i've mentioned?